# How does mono use BSD Sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, winsock

When using a  [`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with mono on Linux, presumably mono will eventually use a BSD socket (and on Windows use a Winsock socket).

Looking at mono's source for say [`Socket.Bind()`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs#L1088) it makes the external call:

```
// Creates a new system socket, returning the handle
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private extern static void Bind_internal(IntPtr sock,
                     SocketAddress sa,
                     out int error);
```

Which says to me mono must be referencing a native library that exposes such a method signature and that native library will take care of the cross-platform implementation (since there is no function named `Bind_internal` on a BSD or Winsock socket).

So my question now becomes which native library is mono using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're slightly misunderstanding, what

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
```

means is that the implementation of that method is within the Mono implementation rather than within an assembly the runtime loads. It may well call into an OS function (for sockets it certainly will: why reimplement an OS service).

*But* it does not have to call an OS service, consider this from the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) in the implementation of `System.String`:

```
public extern int Length {
  [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
  [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
  [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
  get;
 }
```

`String.Length` is embedded directly into the CLR, not in an OS API.

Summary: `InternalCall` means natively implemented inside the runtime. That implementation may call an OS method or it may not: you cannot tell from this level.

To answer your question: I expect that Mono's `Bind_internal` will eventually call [`bind(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) but with some wrapping (a .NET `Socket` has more state and logic than a *nix file descriptor that the OS APIs use).

Comment: To be more exact: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/6f802b490ca568330cd5f32c319609899ba81c8e/mono/metadata/icall-def.h#L450 which maps to https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/6202a690ad14694ed74cdc990215e7dc2944da18/mono/metadata/socket-io.c#L1142 and there look for #if BSD.

Comment: I completely missed what the MethodImplAttribute is and does, thanks.